# DB2 ENCRYPT scalar function - Deprecated

Tags: encryption, db2

I am planning to encrypt my table column data with DB2 provided encryption functions. In this case the suggested option was to use DB2 ENCRYPT Scalar function. However, IBM documentation suggests this function is deprecated. Also, it uses RC2 block cipher algorithm which is considered weak.

Kindly suggest any alternate function for the same, which can be used to encrypt the data.

I tried to search the alternative for the same but couldn't find much help.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be referring to Db2 11.5 and its [ENCRYPT function](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=functions-encrypt). Db2 offers built-in native encryption. It encrypts data at rest and the scope is the database. It is the recommended way if you want to use an encryption offered by the product itself. The documentation has an overview for [data encryption](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=model-data-encryption), discussing all available options for data at rest and data in transit.

If you only want to encrypt single values, you could also implement your own scalar function (as UDF).